# Related Zorn's lemma proof?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, real-numbers

Let $S$ be a partially ordered set, with the additional property that every chain $s_0\le s_1 \le s_2 \le...$ has an upper bound in $S$ (i.e. there is some $t$ in $S$ such that $s_n \le t$ for all $n$). Suppose that $C$ is a countably infinite subset of $S$ such that for every $u$,$v$ in $C$ there is some $w$ in $C$ such that $u\le w$ and $v \le w$. Show that $C$ has an upper bound in $S$.

Any suggestion on how to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Construct a chain in $C$ whose upper bound must be an upper bound for all the elements of $C$.

To do this, enumerate $C = \{ s_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ and construct a new sequence $\{ t_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ inductively: $s_1$ and $s_2$ have an upper bound in $C$, say $t_1$. Then $t_1$ and $s_3$ have an upper bound, say $t_2$. Then $t_2$ and $s_4$ have an upper bound, say $t_3$... and so on.

You need to formalise this argument, prove that the sequence $\{ t_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is a chain in $C$, and that it is a supremum for $C$ in $S$.

Comment: Does the upper bound have to be in C or can it merely be in S?

Comment: The upper bound of the whole chain needn't be in $C$ - remember you're trying to find an upper bound for $C$ in $S$, and the conditions of $C$ say nothing about upper bounds of infinite chains. But each of the $t_n$ must lie in $C$ precisely because of the condition you're putting on $C$ - this is what allows the process to continue.